# Vue.js 3 Mounting component instances at runtime

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying out vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet and was trying to create many instances of `<l-polyline>` inside `<l-map>` component. But I don't know how to achieve that.

Static version (map comes with the polyline drawn):

```
<template>
  <l-map ref="map" v-model:zoom="zoom" :center="[47.41322, -1.219482]">
    <l-polyline
        :lat-lngs="[
        [47.334852, -1.509485],
        [47.342596, -1.328731],
        [47.241487, -1.190568],
        [47.234787, -1.358337],
      ]"
        color="green"
    />
  </l-map>
</template>
```

Dynamic attempt (prepare a function to add polylines programmatically, not working):

```
<template>
  <l-map ref="map" v-model:zoom="zoom" :center="[47.41322, -1.219482]">
  </l-map>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
function someAction(){
let poly= createApp(LPolyline,{
  latLngs:[[47.334852, -1.509485],
    [47.342596, -1.328731],
    [47.241487, -1.190568],
    [47.234787, -1.358337]]
});
poly.mount(this);

}

</script>
```

To clarify, I need a function to insert/append `LPolyline` components into the `LMap` component during runtime, it shouldn't be declared inside the `LMap` initially if possible.

I just started Vue.js so apologies if I'm making an obvious mistake. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the components you want to use, and then feed them with data as any other Vue component. For example, you can load the polylines from an array with `v-for`:

```html
    <l-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
      <l-polyline
        v-for="line in lines"
        :key="line.id"
        :lat-lngs="line.latLongs"
        :color="line.color"
      />
    </l-map>
```

Have a look at the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-vue3-e7vsix)

Comment: `v-for` might be what I'm looking for. Looking good. Thanks for the sandbox example, it helped me a lot to grasp the concept

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  components: {
    'l-map': window.Vue2Leaflet.LMap,
    'l-polyline': window.Vue2Leaflet.LPolyline,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 7,
      latLngs: [[47.334852, -1.509485], [47.342596, -1.328731], [47.241487, -1.190568], [47.234787, -1.358337]]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue2-leaflet"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <l-map ref="map" :zoom="zoom" :center="[47.41322, -1.219482]"  style="height: 300px">
    <l-polyline :lat-lngs="latLngs" color="green"></l-polyline>
  </l-map>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't what I'm looking for. I need a solution where LPolyLine component is added afterwards, it shouldn't be in the component definition initially. Because with the solution i need, I should be able to inject many LPolyLine elements during runtime.